# Is there a podcast app for Ubuntu-touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, podcast

I don't get any result for 'podcast' in the Ubuntu store. Is there really non available for Ubuntu-touch ?

Comment: There is one called "catchpodder": https://launchpad.net/catchpodder

Answer (score 3):

Try searching for "[Podbird](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.mikeasoft.podbird)". It's a highly rated app in the store.

Comment: Thanks found it.. And many others actually (strange that my search was empty the other day)

Answer (score 2):

There ate a few on there, i have seen then before when i have been searching for things. I found it better to seaRch for 'Pod'. One that came up straight away was Pocket Casts.